# problem with slide and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have this structure in my html

```
 <div id ="slide1">
            <form method="post" id="customForm" action="">
                //my content - name, email, mypassword, pass2
            </form> //i already tried delete this
        </div>
        <div id ="slide2">
            <form method="post" id="customForm1" action="">  //and this, to have only one form obviously this didn't work, because the div of slide1 is already closed.
                //my content - other stuff
            </form>
        </div>
```

and i have this JS

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#customForm").submit(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "validation1.php",
                type: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    name: $('#name').val(),
                    email: $('#email').val(),
                    myPassword: $('#myPassword').val(),
                    pass2: $('#pass2').val()
                },
                success: function(data) {
//stuff
}
```

the problem is. I want to group the data of tho slides and send to validation1.php, but for that i must have a only form.

If the problem is not clear please tell me.

thanks

Comment: Why can't you just wrap both divs in a single `form` tag?

Comment: Let me tell you: the problem is not clear.

Comment: at the moment i have two divs. The plug in for the slide requires that- two independent divs. And i need a unique form. At the moment i have two. as I posted i can't delete the first </form> because the div of first slide must be closed. Basically the problem is: if i need to have two divs separately, how i can put a unique form?

Comment: @eykanal, i tried and apparently it solved with you advice

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are saying that you need to send the 2 slides in one post but in your html the data lives in 2 forms elements.

You can always build a new form with the data you want in it and just submit that, but also review the use of forms on your page anyway.

```
var href = '.... where ever you are sending the data .....';
var form = $('<form method="post" action="' + href + '"></form>');

var d1=$('.slide1 some subdata selector');
var d2=$('.slide2 some subdata selector')

$('<input type="hidden" name="data1">').val(d1).appendTo(form);
$('<input type="hidden" name="data2">').val(d2).appendTo(form);
$('body').append(form);
form.submit();
form.detach();
```

Comment: yes, you understand the problem. But i am not sure that is the best way to do this. thanks